# Get contents of subfolders containing a string in their name

Tags: powershell, path, directory, move

I want to get all files in subfolders, of the same root folder, that all contain the same string ("foo") in the name of the subfolder(s). Below gives me no error, and no output. I don't know what I'm missing.

```
Get-ChildItem $rootfolder | where {$_.Attributes -eq 'Directory' -and $_.BaseName -contains 'foo'}) | echo $file
```

Ultimately, I would like to not just echo their names, but move each file to a target folder.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that includes moving the child files of each folder to a new target folder:

```
$RootFolder = '.'
$TargetFolder = '.\Test'

Get-ChildItem $RootFolder | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.BaseName -match 'foo'} |
    ForEach-Object { Get-ChildItem $_.FullName |
    ForEach-Object { Move-Item $_.FullName $TargetFolder -WhatIf } }
```

Remove `-WhatIf` when you are happy it's doing what it should be.

You might need to modify the `Get-ChildItem $_.FullName` part if you (for example) want to exclude sub-directories of the folders, or if you want to include child items in all subfolders of those paths, but not the folders themselves.

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
Get-ChildItem $rootfolder | where {$_.Attributes -match 'Directory' -and $_.basename -Match 'foo'}) | echo $file
```

with

```
Get-ChildItem $rootfolder | where {($_.Attributes -eq 'Directory') -and ($_.basename -like '*foo*')} | Move-Item $targetPath
```

**your request:**

> that all contain the same string ("foo")

you have to use the `-like` comparison operator. Also for exact match I would use `-eq` (case sensitive version is `-ceq`) instead of `-match` since its used for matching substrings and patterns.

**workflow:**
Gets all the files in directory, sending it through pipe to Where-Object cmdlet where you are filtering based on properties Attributes and Basename. When the filtering is done, its being sent to cmdlet Move-Item.

Comment: thank you.. but this will move the subfolders and contents.. i just want to move the contents of each subfolder

Comment: `Get-ChildItem $rootfolder -File -Recurse | where {$_.basename -like '*foo*'} | Move-Item $targetPath ` try this. You have to firstly get all the files (excluding folders) and then filtering it. Let me know if this works and ill update the answer with explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Adapt the first two vars to your environment.

```
$rootfolder = 'C:\Test'
$target = 'X:\path\to\whereever'
Get-ChildItem $rootfolder -Filter '*foo*' | 
  Where {$_.PSiscontainer} | 
    ForEach-Object {
      "Processing folder: {0} " -f $_
     Move $_\*  -Destination $target
   }
```